# disabling my existing AWS access key until I need another one

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

I have an existing AWS account that I was experimenting with.  I know that exposing your AWS key is a major disaster so I have taken care to keep it out of source code and version control.  And, yes, I will use IAM-based authorizations next time I work on AWS.   All I want to do is to make sure the existing key is rendered useless.

I looked at `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html`.  They talk about logging into the AWS console and disabling the keys.

The current version of the console seems slightly different, and there is no option to view or disable an existing key, under **Access Keys (Access Key ID and Secret Access Key)**.  What it does say however is:  *Note: You can have a maximum of two access keys (active or inactive) at a time.*

So what I ended up doing is creating 2 new Access keys and disabling them right away.  I figure that will "flush out" the old existing key, since I've just added my maximum 2 keys.

Does that seem reasonable and secure (as long as no one logs into my AWS console)?

Comment: This seems a better question geared towards Amazon

Comment: Wait... creating *2* new access keys?  What happened to the old one?

Comment: I am kinda hoping it will disappear, because I can only have 2.  Seems like one way to revoke/disable.  And I didn't bother downloading the new ones, so they won't be ending up anywhere.

Comment: When you try the old access keys do they still work?

Comment: that's a good question.  i wasn't planning on really working on AWS any time soon however, and my aws cli is really outdated, so I can't really answer it.  if I get around to it at some point, I'll post it as an answer, but I was hoping that someone had the same question in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable / disable your keys.  Note that you should be doing this as an IAM user, and NEVER as the account (root) owner.

From the IAM console, select the user.  Pick the "Security Credentials" tab, and scroll down to see your keys.  On the right, in the "Status" column, there should be an option to "make inactive".

When you click on that, the option will become "make active".